# Trouble getting table name from meta data from result set

Tags: java, metadata, resultset

I have gotten some meta data from a result set after running executing some sql statement. I want to get the table name from the meta data. I am using

```
Metadata.getTableName(1);
```

But it is returning nothing; what does that mean? Also note that I am able to successfully grab column names from the meta data, just not the table name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use DatabaseMetaData md = connection.getMetaData();

**From javadoc** `which retrieves a DatabaseMetaData object that contains metadata about the database to which this Connection object represents a connection. The metadata includes information about the database's tables, its supported SQL grammar, its stored procedures, the capabilities of this connection, and so on.`

Comment: It's not possible using the result set's meta data? ResultSetMetaData metadata= rs.getMetaData();

Comment: resultset getmetadata retrieves the number, types and properties of this ResultSet object's columns. that's the difference!